# SQL GROUP BY QUERY Not Returning desired output

Tags: sql, oracle

Here are my tables and insert values:

```
create table student (


LastName      varchar(40),
  FirstName     varchar(40),
  SID           number(5),
  SSN           number(9),
  Career        varchar(4),
  Program       varchar(10),
  City          varchar(40),
  Started       number(4),

  primary key (SID),
  unique(SSN)
);
create table enrolled (
  StudentID     number(5),
  CourseID      number(4),
  Quarter       varchar(6),
  Year          number(4),

  primary key (StudentID, CourseID),
  foreign key (StudentID) references student(SID),
  foreign key (CourseID) references course(CID)
);
insert into student
    values ( 'Brennigan', 'Marcus', 90421, 987654321, 'UGRD', 'COMP-GPH', 'Evanston', 2001 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Patel', 'Deepa', 14662, null, 'GRD', 'COMP-SCI', 'Evanston', 2003 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Snowdon', 'Jonathan', 08871, 123123123, 'GRD', 'INFO-SYS', 'Springfield', 2005 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Starck', 'Jason', 19992, 789789789, 'UGRD', 'INFO-SYS', 'Springfield', 2003 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Johnson', 'Peter', 32105, 123456789, 'UGRD', 'COMP-SCI', 'Chicago', 2004 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Winter', 'Abigail', 11035, 111111111, 'GRD', 'PHD', 'Chicago', 2003 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Patel', 'Prakash', 75234, null, 'UGRD', 'COMP-SCI', 'Chicago', 2001 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Snowdon', 'Jennifer', 93321, 321321321, 'GRD', 'COMP-SCI', 'Springfield', 2004 );
insert into enrolled
    values (11035, 1020, 'Fall', 2005);
insert into enrolled
    values (11035, 1092, 'Fall', 2005);
insert into enrolled
    values (11035, 8772, 'Spring', 2006);
insert into enrolled
    values (75234, 3201, 'Winter', 2006);
insert into enrolled
    values (08871, 1092, 'Fall', 2005);
insert into enrolled
    values (90421, 8772, 'Spring', 2006);
insert into enrolled
    values (90421, 2987, 'Spring', 2006);
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT e.studentid
FROM enrolled e 
FULL OUTER JOIN student s ON e.studentid = s.sid 
WHERE ((e.quarter = 'Fall') OR (e.quarter = 'Spring')) 
GROUP BY e.studentid 
HAVING count(e.studentid) = 1;
```

But this only returns

```
8871
```

This should return

```
8871
90421
```

The goal of this query is: List students who were enrolled in at least one course in Fall quarter or at least one course in the Spring quarter, but not both. You will have to add a couple of rows to test your query.

Any help would be appreciated it. Thanks.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Did you meant to use HAVING count(e.studentid) > 1;    There are two records for the student id - 90421 hence count will return 2

Comment: +1 for posting scripts, goal and an attempt to solve the problem. All do like Sohel Mansuri does!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  a.SID
FROM    student a
        INNER JOIN enrolled b
            ON a.SID = b.StudentID
WHERE   b.quarter IN ('Fall', 'Spring')
GROUP   BY a.SID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT b.quarter) = 1
```

Comment: `HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT b.quarter) = 1` will filter only if number of unique `quarter` will be equal to one.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  e.studentid
FROM    enrolled e 
WHERE   e.quarter IN ('Spring', 'Fall')
GROUP BY
        e.studentid 
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT quarter) = 1;
```

`90421` is enrolled in two different courses during spring, that's why your original query counted it twice.

You need to count seasons, not enrollments.

Comment: I still can't rap my head around "HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT quarter) = 1" although I understand that 90421 is enrolled in two different courses during spring.  Can you explain that HAVING part a bit more?

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT quarter)`, um, counts distinct quarters for each student. `HAVING` is a special clause which allows to filter on aggregate functions like `COUNT`. See this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b49b6/6, hoping this will make it more clear.

Comment: you missed the correct answer because the query did not have INNER JOIN with student table. Thanks for the help though. And I +1 it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two records for the student id - 90421 hence count will return 2